# Detecting when GWT uses a fallback user.agent property?

Tags: gwt

There's a number of threads I've found on GWT's handling when it can't find a permutation for a browser i.e. returning of "unknown" which then becomes an attempt to GET a resource named /undefined.cache.js

I've also read and understood how you can use fallback properties to workaround this by setting a fallback user.agent property when no browser permutation is found (suggestions are 'safari' or 'gecko1_8').

What I can't find is a way to detect that the user.agent string has been set from a fallback property so we can popup a message to warn the user they are on an unsupported browser and the UI may not functional fully. In a couple of threads there are vague references to using deferred binding. I'm not an expert in that, although I understand the basic concept, and I can't quite see how that helps - how would deferred binding tell the difference between a user.agent which is actually a 'safari' compatible browser, and hence supported, vs the fact that 'safari' was chosen as fallback for an unsupported browser. Without that, I can't see a way to warn the user.

Hopefully I'm missing something here - at present, I'm on the verge of the much more brittle approach of altering our server to return an HTML error page for that undefined.cache.js resource fetch.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UserAgent`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/useragent/client/UserAgent.html) and compare the runtime vs compile time values. The compile time value does not take into account the fallback value.

Comment: OK - that's a handy tip, will give it a try

Comment: Sorry - showing my inexperience in the depths of GWT. How does one get an instance of UserAgent - seems to be an interface, and not seeing any obvious classes that implement it or get methods which return it.

Comment: `GWT.create(UserAgent.class)`

Comment: OK, bit stumped here - the UserAgent.class stuff is working fine - but the user.agent fallback handling doesn't seem to be working at all.   We're on 2.8RC2, as I understand it the fallback came in in GWT2.7. Have tried with both <set-property-fallback name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/> and <set-property-fallback name="gxt.user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/> (as we use GXT). Doesn't seem to matter where I put these in the .xml file - we still get the  /undefined.cache.js request when I force browser into IE7 mode

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to set the user agent properties at least with GXT. I suspect you want to collapse the permutations because the build is taking so long to compile all the permutations. Why are you trying t set them? http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/gwt/Permutations.html